# web scraping aspx web page with R

Tags: asp.net, r, xpath, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape 'http://www.phl.org/Pages/Flight-Information.aspx#/Arrivals' web page in R to get the arrivals schedule (and then eventually departures as well) of flights in Philadelphia International Airport. This is the code I have written so far:

```
require("rvest")
require("dplyr")

url1 <- "http://www.phl.org/Pages/Flight-Information.aspx#/Arrivals"
url2 <- '//*[@id="ctl00_pageWrapper"]/main/div[3]/table'

Trial_data <- url1 %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes(xpath=url2) %>%    html_table() %>% data.frame()
```

However, this scrapes only the headers of the table and not the table data itself. I have inspected the web page elements from the website's HTML code and used the Xpath in my script. As a trial, I used the same piece of code to scrape a wikipedia table and it worked perfectly fine. I feel the problem is with .aspx web page.

would really appreciate any help on this !!

Comment: As far as I can see the table content is populated dynamically using AngularJs so this data might not be available without running and getting the result of the AJAX call first.

Comment: rvest just grabs the HTML, so the data isn't getting loaded. You could use RSelenium to load the page (running any necessary scripts in the process), and then rvest to parse, but it's more work. Given this particular data, though, I'm sure there's an API somewhere that exposes this same data in a more usable format, so a bit of searching may be a better next step.

Comment: [Here's an API.](https://github.com/CityOfPhiladelphia/phl-airport-data)

Comment: ...so your call could be as simple as `arrivals <- jsonlite::fromJSON('http://flightinfo.phlapi.com/direction/arrival')`

Comment: @alistaire , thank you so much for your response. This pushes me in the right direction, really appreciate it !!

Comment: @kieraf - Thanks, this helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above are correct the html code is populated dynamically thus the `rvest` library will not work.  If you load the web page with the developer tools turned on and examine the files downloaded, there are couple of files of XHR type.  If you examine these files these file the one named FlightTracker.ashx is a JSON file containing the information you are requesting.

Once the file and curl is determine it is just the matter of making a httr request and parse the JSON file:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

url<-'http://www.phl.org/_layouts/15/Fuseideas.PHL.SharePoint/FlightTrackerXml.ashx?dir=A'
flightdata<-GET(url)

output<- content(flightdata, as="text") %>% fromJSON(flatten=FALSE)
```

FYI: you may want to look at this file:
 'http://www.phl.org/Style%20Library/PHL/Scripts/Angular/iata-data.jsn' which contains information on airlines' and airports' abbreviations, names and links.

Comment: thanks for your answer, the code worked and it really helped me !! I still couldn't locate the FlightTracker.ashx file. I also see that the url is slightly different than the one I used. Can you let me know how you managed to locate the url and the .ashx file?

Comment: Open your desired web page.  The menu and option names will vary depending which browser you are using.  Then with the page open, turn on the web inspector option (under the developer tools menu), select the Network tab and then reload the web page.  The network tag will list all of the files associated with the web page:  html, css, js and json.  It is then a  matter of looking at each file to find your data.